# Creating index file for import into document management system using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to write a PowerShell script to create a single index file that I can use to import a large list of documents into our document management system.

A couple of things:

- All of the documents are located in the same folder.
- All documents are the same type, .pdf
- All of the information needed to create the index is in the filename of the respective document.

The format of required index file would be a .txt, and here is the format of each new line in the .txt file:

- IndexField1,IndexField2,IndexField3@DocumentPath

Three example documents:

- C:\Test\Doe, John - Alphabet Elementary - 1st Grade.pdf
- C:\Test\Bay, Michael - Transformer High - 12th Grade.pdf
- C:\Test\Shyamalan, M. Night - Personality High - 10th Grade.pdf

The ending index file would need to look like this using the above examples:

- Doe,John,Alphabet Elementary,1st Grade@C:\Test\Doe, John - Alphabet Elementary - 1st Grade.pdf
- Bay, Michael,Transformer High,12th Grade@C:\Test\Bay, Michael - Transformer High - 12th Grade.pdf
- Shyamalan, M. Night,Personality High,10th Grade@C:\Test\Shyamalan, M. Night - Personality High - 10th Grade.pdf

I can create a .txt file listing all of the document within the folder.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Test\ -name | Out-File C:\Test\results.txt
```

However, I don't know where to begin to parse each line of the results.txt and append the appropriate information to get the format needed for the index file.

Any suggestions or example to lead with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the objects returned by your `Get-ChildItem`. Then you can use `-split` or `-replace` with a regex to filter out the individual pieces you are looking for. Then combine those into the formatting you need for the output.

```
$Output = Get-ChildItem C:\Test\ | ForEach-Object {
    $Last = ($_.BaseName -split ',')[0]
    $First = $_.BaseName -replace '(^.*?,\s)(.*?)(\s-\s.*)','$2'
    $School = $_.BaseName -replace '(^.*?\s-\s)(.*?)(\s-\s.*)','$2'
    $Grade = ($_.BaseName -split ' - ')[-1]
    $Path = $_.FullName

    # Unsure if there is supposed to be a space before first name.
    "$Last, $First,$School,$Grade@$Path"
}
$Output | Out-File C:\Test\results.txt
```

Your output looks like a .csv without the header and without the proper quotations. If your document management system (DMS) does require properly formatted .csvs then you could create the array of objects then export them in CSV format. Using `ConvertTo-CSV` then `Select-Object -Skip 1` will allow you to skip the header on the file.

```
$Output = Get-ChildItem C:\Test\ | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Last = ($_.BaseName -split ',')[0]
        First = $_.BaseName -replace '(^.*?,\s)(.*?)(\s-\s.*)','$2'
        School = $_.BaseName -replace '(^.*?\s-\s)(.*?)(\s-\s.*)','$2'
        GradeAtPath = "$(($_.BaseName -split ' - ')[-1])@$($_.FullName)"
    }
}
$Output | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File C:\Test\results.txt
```